# Nested For Loop in Java method to check for Duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, iteration, nested-for-loop

I am a beginner and I have been trying to debug my code for several days now to figure out why my loop in isDuplicate does not seem to work correctly. I've scoured the site for ideas but none seem to fix my issue.

The goal is to have the user input an item, then call the method to check if that item is already in the array. If it isn't, it should be added. If it is a duplicate, it should give an error message.

I can only use loops for this, as the goal is to learn implementation of the various loops in java.

When I run the program, it says the first inputted item is a duplicate. Each subsequent item input is not found to be a duplicate. There seems to be a logic error in either my for-loop iteration or if statement that I am overlooking.

Any advice is really appreciated. I've tried to search for answers in books and online all week and I have hit a roadblock.

```
/*
 Grocery List that accepts input, sorts by item name,
 checks for duplicates and outputs list to user.
 */
public class Main {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0; // Number of items currently in the grocery list
        String[] groceryList = new String[6];

        /*
        invoke method to check for duplicate entries.
        use while loop for input from user
        */
        while (count < groceryList.length) {
            System.out.print("Enter a grocery item: ");
            String item = input.nextLine();
            isDuplicate(item, groceryList, count);
            groceryList[count] = item;
            count++;
        }

        // sort elements and use for-each loop to print list
        Arrays.sort(groceryList);
        System.out.println("Your Grocery List: ");
        for (String food : groceryList) {
            System.out.println(food);
        }
    }

    /*
       I know there is an issue with my loop but I could not figure it out.
       Says first element is duplicate but no others.
       Cannot use collections. can only use for loops for this method.
     */
    public static boolean isDuplicate(String item, String[] list, int listcnt) {
        for (listcnt = 0; listcnt < list.length; listcnt++) {
            for (int j = listcnt + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
                if (list[j] == list[listcnt])
                    System.out.println("Sorry, " + item + " is a duplicate.");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have several problems.  Your best strategy to learn is to step through the code carefully, one line at a time, in your IDE debugger, and determine where the behavior deviates from your expectations.  One problem is `if (list[j] == list[listcnt])` should use `equals()` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the Java code for a minute and think through it logically and come up with an algorithm in your head.

You have an item - not yet in the list (this is important). You have a list of items. You want to see if the item is in the list of items already.

How would you do this for a list on paper?

- Scan the list for the item? Sounds right
- Does that require looping through the list twice? Nope

You also don't check the result of the isDuplicate check and always add the item

```
isDuplicate(item, groceryList, count);
groceryList[count] = item;
```

Typically in Java we don't use `==` to compare objects: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/

```
if (list[j] == list[i])
```

Comment: I agree, I try to write out pseudo code and as a newbie, I'm still trying to think like a computer. All of your answers helped point out the flaws and this was a great learning experience that helped me continue moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you do not use the result of `isDuplicate()`:

```
/*
 Grocery List that accepts input, sorts by item name,
 checks for duplicates and outputs list to user.
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] groceryList = readGroceryList(6);
        // sort elements and use for-each loop to print list
        Arrays.sort(groceryList);
        print(groceryList);
    }

    private static String[] readGroceryList(int total) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] groceryList = new String[total];
        int count = 0; // Number of items currently in the grocery list

        /*
        invoke method to check for duplicate entries.
        use while loop for input from user
        */
        while (count < groceryList.length) {
            System.out.print("Enter a grocery item: ");
            String item = scan.nextLine();

            if (isDuplicate(item, groceryList, count))
                System.err.println("Sorry, " + item + " is a duplicate.");
            else
                groceryList[count++] = item;
        }

        return groceryList;
    }

    private static void print(String[] groceryList) {
        System.out.println("Your Grocery List: ");

        for (String food : groceryList)
            System.out.println(food);
    }

    /*
       I know there is an issue with my loop but I could not figure it out.
       Says first element is duplicate but no others.
       Cannot use collections. can only use for loops for this method.
     */
    public static boolean isDuplicate(String item, String[] groceryList, int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            if (item.equals(groceryList[i]))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to look this over and get some tips for making my code better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your `isDuplicate()` method. Here's the standard way to scan for duplicates in an array:

```
    public static boolean isDuplicate(String item, String[] list){
        //iterate the array
        for(String listItem : list){
            //check if "item" matches "listItem"
            if(item.equals(listItem)){
                return true;
            }
            //NOTE: if you want this to not be case sensetive,
            //e.g. if you want "somestring" to be equal to "SomeString", do
//            if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(listItem)){
//                return true;
//            }
        }
        //we only get this far in the method if the item is not in the list
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped solve part of my issue. I was able to return the info back up into my main method and go from there to get it up and running. I really appreciate your input.